# How can I program a dynamic sitemap in django, mine not working

Tags: django, sitemap, sitemap.xml

The static part works fine but the dynamic posts of my blog app are not generated

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Post

class PostSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "weekly"
    priority = 0.9

    def items(self):
        return Post.objects.all()
```

I'm not able to get a dynamic sitemap with my blog and my Post class in models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
header_image = models.ImageField(null=True , blank=True, upload_to="images/")
title_tag=models.CharField(max_length=100)
author= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
body = RichTextUploadingField(extra_plugins=
['youtube', 'codesnippet'], external_plugin_resources= [('youtube','/static/ckeditor/youtube/','plugin.js'), ('codesnippet','/static/ckeditor/codesnippet/','plugin.js')])
#body = models.TextField()
post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
category = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='uncategorized')
snippet = models.CharField(max_length=200)
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='blog_posts')

def total_likes(self):
    return self.likes.count()

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Entrada"
    verbose_name_plural = "Entradas"
    ordering = ['-post_date']

def __str__(self):
    return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('home')
```

If any one can help me I would be very grateful.
urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from theblog.sitemaps import PostSitemap, StaticSitemap
        
        sitemaps = {'static': StaticSitemap, 'blog': PostSitemap}
```

Comment: But your `def get_absolute_url(self):` reverses to `home`? That means the "detail view" of all these posts is the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: The `get_absolute_url()` should implement a *canonical URL* to the object.

In order to generate the sitemap. Django will call the [**`.location(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#django.contrib.sitemaps.Sitemap.location) of the `Sitemap` object on each element. If no `.location(…)` method is defined, as is the case here. It will call the [**`.get_absolute_url(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) on the model object.

You implemented a `get_absolute_url` method, but it looks like:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('home')
```

this means that all the "detail pages" for the `Post` objects are apparently the home page, so this is the only page that will be in the sitemap. It is also not really satisfying the conditions of the `.get_absolute_url(…)` method:

> Define a `get_absolute_url()` method to tell Django how to calculate the **canonical URL** for an object. To callers, this method should appear to return a string that can be used to refer to the object over HTTP.

A canonical URL means that it is normally *unique* per object. So if you have a path defined like:

```
    path('post/<int:pk>', post_details, name='post_details')
```

then often the canonical url is:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post_details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: You solved it. Not a programmer myself, I still fail in the most basic things, very thank you.